# Cannot run an image pulled from ctr with docker

Tags: docker, containerd, ctr

I'm learning docker and I wanted to tests some stuff about containerd and its command line, with docker, So I pulled an image (in my example docker.io/library/python:3.8.18-bookworm) with ctr command, and running it with docker but I got an error like it can't found my id image

So, I resume:
First, I pulled an image with ctr: 
ctr image pull docker.io/library/python:3.8.18-bookworm 
docker run -it --rm image_id bash 
docker: Error Response drom daemon: No such image: sha256:image_id

Comment: Containerd and Docker are different tools and they don't share common storage. An image pulled in one won't be visible in the other. If you want to use an image with Docker, use `docker pull`.

Comment: Yes I know that but it is impossible to give it a full path ?

Comment: Yes. Neither tool accepts "a path" as a way to specify an image, and I don't even know if the underlying storage formats are compatible.

Comment: I see, Thank you for your explanations!